# Using AI to find the correct set of object/numbers based on previous data

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

There are 11 objects of which 4 are "Bad" objects. So there are 7 "Good" objects.
You have to choose as many Good objects before proceeding to another set of objects of a different sequence.

How would you train an AI that predicts the position of the Good objects based of previous sets of data?